# Facebook login having issue (php sdk)

Tags: php, html

I am using php sdk for facebook login on my website. But i am facing a very stupid problem, when i click on connect facebook button it redirects me to facebook website to enter email and password but after redirecting back to my website it creates infinite loop which does not end.

This is my code:

```
require('facebook/facebook.php');

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'app_id',
    'secret' => 'app_secret',
  ));

  // See if there is a user from a cookie

      $user = $facebook->getUser();
      //echo $user;
      if ($user) {
        try {
          // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
          $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
          $user = null;
        }
      }

print"<pre>";
  print_r($user_profile);
  print"</pre>";
```

You can test the it on this url:

```
http://www.conceptbeans.co.uk/cb/projects/xedact/login.php
```

I will be appreciable any help from your side.

Thanks
Zain

Comment: What do you expect from the URL? I get back my FB profile ID.

Comment: You are saying that you log in successfully from this url?

Comment: I just saying that when i connect to facebook on my website so it creates a redirect loop and i give you a url for testing, Also i want what is the issue? That's it

Answer (score 0):

your syntax isnt correct when you define your new facebook object, you have a `,` at the end of array. should be:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'app_id',
    'secret' => 'app_secret'
  ));
```

Comment: I cannot get the user after redirecting back to my website, also it is  creating redirecting loop. I checked the syntax error which you point out but it still same

Comment: are you using the latest version of the sdk? [link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)

Comment: Yes i am using the latest version of sdk, downloaded it from github

Comment: check your app settings on facebook, [check this image](http://4de08c6af39c20343f39-fec7c301d7eca18188203e783b444e60.r36.cf1.rackcdn.com/2011/04/app_setting.jpg)